# Exponential curve by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, exponential

I have this dataset:

```
head(long_format_female)

SampleID  variable       value
      R1     Week7      0.0000
      R1     Week9    478.8631
      R1    Week11  14412.3013
      R1    Week13 146708.1029
      R1    Week15 265801.9593
      R1    Week17 518708.2570
      R1    Week19 978497.0982
      R1    Week21          NA
      R2     Week7      0.0000
      R2     Week9      0.0000
      R2    Week11      0.0000
      R2    Week13      0.0000
      R2    Week15      0.0000
      R2    Week17    440.5659
      R2    Week19   1551.0876
      R2    Week21  12523.7732
```

I would like to plot the individual exponential curves (one line for each `SampleID`) showing the trait growth across weeks. I have tried this code that gives me the expected output figure with geom_points shown, but no geom_line.

```
ggplot(long_format_female, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = factor(SampleID))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = y ~ a*exp(b *x), aes(colour = 'Exponential'), se = FALSE, start = list(a=1,b=1)) + xlab("Time(weeks)") +
  ylab("Trait") + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

I also get these two messages:

```
geom_smooth: Only one unique x value each group.Maybe you want aes(group = 1)?
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

How can I add the `geom_line` to my plot?

Comment: Does using 'group=sampleID' solve your issue?

Comment: Of note, make sure that the factor levels are in the right order when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience you need to have numerical values for both x and y if you are going to use `geom_line`, `geom_point` is confusingly more tolerant about factors.

Note: after a discussion with Heroka we noticed that `geom_line` works okay with "grouped factors" (i.e. if you specify a group parameter in your plot), but does not like them ungrouped and complains and does not draw a line.

I really don't know what you want to do with the smooth though, and I would probably need better data. In anycase there is no `start` parameter in the current ggplot2 2.0.0 `stat_smooth`, so you might want to consider updating your ggplot2 before you go any further.

So here is a start:

```
# fake some data
set.seed(1235)
weeks <- sprintf("week%d",1:9)
nsid <- 5
nwk <- 8
k <- 1
lst <- list()
slst <- list()
for (i in 1:nsid){
  sid <- sprintf("R%d",i)
  for (j in 1:nwk){
    wk <- sprintf("week%d",j)
    v <- round(i*rnorm(1,200,1) + rnorm(1,3,0.2)^j,1)
    lst[[k]] <- list(sid,i,wk,j,v)
    k <- k+1
  }
}
df <- lapply(data.frame(do.call(rbind,lst)),unlist) # combine then flatten
names(df) <- c("s","i","w","j","v")
long_format_female <- data.frame(SampleID=df$s,variable=df$w,value=df$v)

# need a numeric version of this factor
long_format_female$nvariable <- as.numeric(long_format_female$variable)

ggplot(long_format_female, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = SampleID)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = nvariable, y = value)) +

  xlab("Time(weeks)") +
  ylab("Trait") + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Geom_line works perfectly fine with factors on the x-axis, but OP's question needs a grouping variable (I've tested with their data)

Comment: Not what I got when I tested but will have a look at what is going on when  get back.

Comment: Was working on something and added it anyway :) - Maybe you don't need it now. Still think you are on the old ggplot though.

Comment: @Heroka would like to chat with you about the factors. `geom_line` does not work with factors on the x-axis as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MikeWise OK, but here might not be the right location